# Google charts and database - what to learn in java for this?

Tags: java, database, servlets, google-visualization

recently i discovered Google Charts and it will be very good tool for me. I'd like to create web application, so i started learning java and java servlets (JSP), and also start reading about Spring. But.. this variety of frameworks, servlets and all stuff related to creating web app is difficult to understand for me..

My goal is web application with charts with values from my Firebird's database.

I'm programming in Eclipse.

I've noticed that on stackoverflow are few topics about database and google charts, but i'd like that somebody could show me way of achieving my goal, without learning everything about java.

Comment: This is really a ton of questions hiding: How to write a web app? How to access a Firebird database? How to setup a web app server? How to use Google Charts in a web app. Please edit it to be way more specific (or post a bunch of specific questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Google Chart, its just a URL you are generating for your JSP. You don't have to learn anything special, other than how Google charts works.  If you are using a database you may need to learn JDBC or a database framework.